# Capture/Restream streaming web cam video over network with VLC or Python

Tags: python, video-streaming, html5-video, video-capture, vlc

I have streaming video from a web cam that is accessible via a public ip I opened up on my machine.  As in I can go to http//ip/webview and view the video with (I did have to install the activex hidvrocx.cab plugin).  The video source itself is h.264 and, according to wireshark, is running on port 9000 over tcp.

What I would like to do is re-stream the raw video, but at this point I would settle for converting it to FLV so I can open is with VLC or something...

According to the technical support team of the webcam (Swann), "netviewer" (some third party software) can view the video feed so there is no encryption / special DRM.

I'm new to this whole thing streaming video world, so this is what I've tried / am considering:
- I've tried loading the stream using VLC at tcp://public_ip:9000, but according to swann support VLC can not view the source because it is raw h.264.  Is it possible to use vlc to convert this raw h.264 format into something readable to media players. Possibly...?

```
vlc src --sout flv
```

- Is it possible to use the python VideoCapture library?  Is this strictly for capturing video directly for the device, or does it work over the network?

I'm completely lost right now, so even seeing the raw stream in a media player of any type would be an accomplishment.

TLDR; I have a streaming video source from a webcam over a public IP I would like to ultimately "redistribute" in it's original format (h.264) or flv.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

```
vlc <input_stream> --sout=#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=<server_ip>:<port>/}
```

This command will re-stream your Input stream to http with ts muxer
Also you can try rtp/rtsp:

```
vlc <input_stream> --sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://<server_ip>:<port>/XXX.sdp}
```

will re-stream to rstp protocal